# Add Play Music's download folder to the library of Samsung Music?

Tags: music, music-player, google-play-music

I use a Galaxy Note 4 (Android 6.0.1), and I like the default music player more than Play Music's player, however, I enjoy to have my music everywhere, and managed by Play Music. I'm looking for a way to manage my music using Play Music and play my music using Samsung Music, however, files downloaded through Play Music don't appear in the library of Samsung Music.

Is there a way to add the following folder to Samsung Music's library folder?
/external_sd/Android/data/com.google.android.music/files/music/

I even thought of a symlink of some sort but it doesn't seem possible to do that without root. Also, my phone is not rooted and I won't root while still in warranty.